# HTTP 415 OPTIONS request between Angular 2 and .net core web app running on IIS using CORS

Tags: http, angular, iis, asp.net-core, cors

I have a .net core web app (api) running in IIS being called from an Angular2 app. The http call is making an options request call first as I'm setting the content-type custom header on a POST call. IIS (I assume) is returning the 415 (unsupported media type) on the options call.

Where do I need to set supported media types in IIS (or .net core)?

Client request:

```
let postparams = {
  Action: 'DoStuff'
};
let body = JSON.stringify(postparams);

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept','application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

var url = 'http://localhost:9056/api/resolve';
var response = this.http.post(url, body, options).map(res => res.json());
```

Options request from fiddler generated by Angular (returns 415):

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:9056/api/resolve HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9056
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8
```

POST request that works in fiddler (returns 200):

```
POST http://localhost:9056/api/resolve HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9056
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 26
Origin: http://localhost:8100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8

{"Action":"DoStuff"}
```

If I set the content-type to text/plain then I get a 415 returned - do I need to set up in IIS or .net core that the return type is application/json somehow?

Thanks in advance community!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so my problem in the end was around CORS. I was setting the CORS headers via IIS but setting them in .net core Startup resolved my problem. The Unsupported Media Type response code was throwing me off...

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        // Needed to add this section, and....
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // ..... this line
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

If I can save someone else some head scratching then happy days!

Comment: Unconditionally Enabling CORS is not safe for production use. Consider to wrap CORS configuration with #if DEBUG or IsDevelopment or proper CORS policy to describe list of valid origins